# How forward pass and inference are different in pytorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Looking at encoder part of Tacotron2 model:

https://github.com/mozilla/TTS/blob/master/layers/tacotron2.py#L63

https://github.com/mozilla/TTS/blob/master/layers/tacotron2.py#L77

I wonder why forward and inference are different?

```
def forward(self, x, input_lengths):
    x = self.convolutions(x)
    x = x.transpose(1, 2)
    input_lengths = input_lengths.cpu().numpy()
    x = nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(
        x, input_lengths, batch_first=True)
    self.lstm.flatten_parameters()
    outputs, _ = self.lstm(x)
    outputs, _ = nn.utils.rnn.pad_packed_sequence(
        outputs,
        batch_first=True,
    )
    return outputs

def inference(self, x):
    x = self.convolutions(x)
    x = x.transpose(1, 2)
    self.lstm.flatten_parameters()
    outputs, _ = self.lstm(x)
    return outputs
```

Is it related to LSTM layer only?

Comment: It's not necessarily related to LSTMs. I have a different `inference` and `forward` method because I have to do some tiling of the input images which are too large otherwise. I suppose it has something to do with batching but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly because of using `pack_padded_sequence` and `pad_packed_sequence` to save calculation when doing batch training with padding and speed up training. see https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/understanding-pack-padded-sequence-and-pad-packed-sequence/4099/5?u=ijnf

There are other reasons to have separate forward, inference methods so it's somewhat common..

Answer (score 0):

The only reason is for training batches. When you want to train batch with different length, you have to pad them to same length so you can adapt to torch's input structure.`pad_packed_sequence`  is a tool to help RNN read faster.